# Settings up user library in eclipse on MAC OS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am trying to include two user libraries for my Java program.
I tried including the JAR files as "external JARS" and as a part of a "user library". But neither worked.
I keep getting the error message:

```
The import edu cannot be resolved   checkjava.java  /algs1/src  line 1  Java Problem
```

This is the screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/weicq.jpg

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You sure the method shouldn't be `StdOut.println("Hello World");` instead of `StdOut.prinln("Hello World");`? Seems like a simple syntax error in there as well.

Comment: Did you look at Eclipse Help? What else have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks hdtsn. The function is actually part of the imported libraries. Had they worked then I wouldn't get this error. Other students in the class I am taking had this function working once the imported libraries got recognized.
Gparyani, I tried having the whole project name as the class name but that also did not work. Not sure what else to try.